# TextInputEditText resizing text

Tags: android, kotlin, android-textinputedittext

I have this TextInputEditText widget (Material Design)

when there is too much text on the field, it gets cut off. I want to resize it until a certain size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library for this which supports min/max size: [AutoFitEditText](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText)

---

**P.S.** Probably you know, but, if anyone ended up here wondering about auto resize textviews they need something like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

From:[Autosizing TextViews](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)